# How to Return to the First Line in a Urlopen Object

Tags: python, iteration, urllib2, urlopen

I am iterating a .dat file save on a http website using

```
import urllib2
test_file = urllib2.urlopen('http://~/file.dat')
```

And then, I have a function which iterates the file

```
def f(file):
    while True:
        iter = file.readline()
        if iter == "":
            break
        print iter
```

If I want to call this function twice without opening the test_file again:

```
f(test_file)
f(test_file)
```

then what should I add into the f function?

Update:
Since I am not allowed to change anything outside the function, I finally came up a silly but effective solution:

```
def f(file):
    while True:
        iter = file.readline()
        if iter == "":
            break
        print iter
        global test_file
        test_file = test_file = urllib2.urlopen('http://~/file.dat')
```

Thanks for the guys who answered my questions!

Comment: `test_file` is a handle to a file that you have already **opened**. calling `f(test_file)` multiple times is simply moving through the file in memory already.

Comment: Yep, I know that. So do you have any idea what to add in the function like a     seek() in a normal file.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.seek(0)
```

returns you to the start of the file.  The argument is the byte position in the file.

Comment: but it doesn't work for urlopen files since it is just a "file-like" object

Answer (score 0):

So the best thing for you to do is to save the output of your f.read() to a var and then push through via the `StringIO.readline()` method that will work similarly to `f.readline()` but within memory.

```
import urllib2
import StringIO

t_fh = urllib2.urlopen('http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/sgb/test.dat')
test_data = t_fh.read()


def f(data):
    buf = StringIO.StringIO(data)
    while True:
        line = buf.readline()
        if line == "":
            break
        print line

f(test_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cannot save the test data as a file. I've come up with my own solution. You can see it in the update part in my question.